# Producing LaTeX output in Java

Tags: java, latex

Is there a Java library for producing LaTeX output from Java?

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you expect from what input?

Comment: It seems there is no... maybe it is acceptable to use two steps? Generate docbook files and then convert them to latex.

Comment: @khachick: haven't you read my answer below?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 14):

To render Latex:

JLatexMath: https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath

To produce Latex:

JTex: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtex/

Comment: Isn't that one for **rendering** LaTeX?

Comment: going by the examples of usage and the fact it doesn't have any dependencies, yes it renders LaTeX.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's not what is asked for. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Note: You have to fetch JTex from SVN.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with [JLaTeXMath](https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath):

> "JLaTeXMath is the best Java library to display LaTeX code."

```java
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXConstants;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormula;

public class Example5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String latex = "\\begin{array}{|c|l|||r|c|}";
        latex += "\\hline";
        latex += "\\text{Matrix}&\\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\\text{Multicolumns}}&\\text{Font sizes commands}\\cr";
        latex += "\\hline";
        latex += "\\begin{pmatrix}\\alpha_{11}&\\cdots&\\alpha_{1n}\\cr\\hdotsfor{3}\\cr\\alpha_{n1}&\\cdots&\\alpha_{nn}\\end{pmatrix}&\\Large \\text{Large Right}&\\small \\text{small Left}&\\tiny \\text{tiny Tiny}\\cr";
        latex += "\\hline";
        latex += "\\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\\Huge \\text{Huge Multicolumns}}\\cr";
        latex += "\\hline";
        latex += "\\end{array}";

        TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula(latex);
        formula.createPNG(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20, "target/Example5.png", Color.white, Color.black);
    }
}
```

### Other solutions to evaluate

- [SnuggleTeX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) - seems to have a good parser, too. See the calling at https://sourceforge.net/p/snuggletex/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/snuggletex-core/src/main/java/uk/ac/ed/ph/snuggletex/samples/MinimalExample.java.
- [JavaTex](http://javatex.sourceforge.net/): https://sourceforge.net/projects/javatex/files/javatex/V0.2/. Seems to be a complete LaTeX engine.
- [JavaTeX from CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/javatex?lang=de) - from 1998, but might still perform well.

(partially based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41609/9075)