# How do I import a latex package into my programs?

Tags: java, package, latex

I want to output some equations with Latex. I have searched and found this page:

[Producing LaTeX output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229190/producing-latex-output-in-java)

But I don't know how to use the libraries mentioned in the answers.

Is there a native command I can use like, something like `import java.util.Scanner;`, that will enable me to use latex in my java program?

Comment: *Is there some command I can use like import java.util.Scanner; that will enable me to use latex in my java program?* **Absolutely *not***.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add package ***jlatexmath*** in your project. For more desc in case use Replit move to https://blog.replit.com/maven

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).